# Get 404 on discountasp.net IIS 8, Using Web Api RPC-style web service, apiController

Tags: rpc, asp.net-web-api, iis-8, discountasp

My application works great when I deploy to my local machine, IIS 7.  On Discountasp.net it will launch the application, but none of the calls to the web service work.
I get "IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found".
I recently upgraded my account to "Windows 2012 - IIS 8.0", and other kinds of web-service applications I have there are working great.

The application is built in Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.5, with a Web Service : RPC style (not REST) Web Api with the apiController.

For example, some code that I'm calling with jQuery ajax:

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]    
    public ItemsReturn PostItemsSorted(ItemsSortedRequest inputs) 
    {
        ItemGetSortedCaller cls = new ItemGetSortedCaller();
        ItemsReturn ret = cls.CallGetSortedItems(inputs);
        return ret;
    }
 }

    var inputdata = {searchWord:searchWord, 
                     sortColumn:sortColumn
                     };

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "/api/Item/PostItemsSorted";
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
            context: this
        });
```

I've searched everywhere, and have no clue. Why the 404?

Comment: Does it work your local VS development server?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web, and the web service works when I'm in the IDE, so, I guess you would say that it works on the built-in Development Server.

Comment: I guess you need to talk to your hosting provider then :(

Comment: I talked to discountasp.net, but they just said they couldn't debug my application.  I have to post to forums and search until I find the answer.  Thanks, though.